# How does make command doesnot search for Makefile in the same directory first?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using the command `make` for compiling source codes.  However, the command always issue this error

> Makefile:10: Makefile_compiler_*HOSTNAME*: No such file or directory
> make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile_compiler_*HOSTNAME*'.  Stop.

where *HOSTNAME* is the hostname of my computer.  It seems like `make` is defaulted to search for the file Makefile_compiler_*HOSTNAME* before the file Makefile.

Is there any way to set the default behaviour of `make` back?

Comment: Can you share your Makefile? It actually looks like line 10 in the Makefile is the issue.

Comment: @PranavKasetti The line 10 in the Makefile reads

`include $(SRC_DIR)/Makefile_compiler_HOSTNAME`

This is strange because I downloaded the source files in ZIP format from GITHUB.  How does it contains something relevant to my HOSTNAME?

Comment: Look in your folder for something that starts with Makefile_compiler_. If you find a folder with the same prefix but a different Hostname, replace the HOSTNAME in line 10 with that.